# Extending an underline in CSS

Tags: html, css, underline

Is it possible to over extend and underline so that it goes further than the word itself?

Like so:

[image]

I tried:

```
.numbers u {
    width:200px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FZu9p/)

I was hoping it would work but I got nothing.

Is there some sort of css trick to make this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property with [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo, if you do not want to use this, than you need to feed `&nbsp;` on each `u` tag

```
.numbers u:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZu9p/3/)

Info: What's 00a0 here? It's a [Non Break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)

Can also use something like

```
.numbers u:after {
    content: "................";
    color: transparent;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZu9p/9/) *(But I would prefer `\00a0` one..)*

---

As far as browser support goes, `content` as well as `:after` are supported in IE8, Side note, `::after` is supported in IE9 but using `:after` is just fine here. so support shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Wow that is such a crazy way to do it! but it does exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: Cool one Aley, +1 , but just provide him the browser compatability for `:after`.

Comment: Just to add further light to what Mr. Alien has suggested, you can add an `&nbsp;` on the text where you want the underline extension, and you will get the output as you want. Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FZu9p/8/ - @Adsy

Comment: @Adsy This is no hack, it's completely legal :) \@Nathan Lee thanks a lot pal :)

Answer (score 6):

No. You need to put a `border-bottom` and extend the width of the `p` where the text exists.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FZu9p/2/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<p class="underline">One</p>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.underline{border-bottom:1px solid #000000; width:200px; padding-bottom:5px;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use a border rather than underlining. Use the `first-child` pseudo class to apply it to only the first paragraph within `.numbers`:

```
.numbers p:first-child {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZu9p/5/)

Comment: I only want the line for top number, is it possible to use your example but set a p class to just the top number?

Comment: Yep, you can use the `first-child` pseudo class, see my edit.